# conversion from BitmapImage to byte array causing high memory usage

Tags: c#, memory, image-processing, bitmapimage

I have jpeg.
I convert it to a BitmapImage.
I then reduce the quality (compression).
I then covert to byte array.
I have found the memory escalates very quickly in task manager.

I am certain I am disposing all that I can.

This is my code:

```
//I am calling this from within a timer set 500ms
byte[] datatest = JpegXr.SaveJpegXrToBytes((Bitmap)frame.Clone(), 40f);
frame.Dispose();


public static class JpegXr
{
    public static Bitmap BitmapImage2Bitmap(BitmapImage bitmapImage)
    {
        // BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("../Images/test.png", UriKind.Relative));

        using (MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            BitmapEncoder enc = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
            enc.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmapImage));
            enc.Save(outStream);
            System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(outStream);

            // return bitmap; <-- leads to problems, stream is closed/closing ...
            return new Bitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }

    public static byte[] SaveJpegXrToBytes(Bitmap bitmap, float quality)
    {
        byte[] data = null;
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        SaveJpegXr(bitmap, quality, stream);
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        data= stream.ToArray();
        stream.Close();
        bitmap.Dispose();
        return data;
    }

    private static BitmapImage Bitmap2BitmapImage(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        BitmapSource bitmapSource = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
                       bitmap.GetHbitmap(),
                       IntPtr.Zero, System.Windows.Int32Rect.Empty,
                       BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());

        //BitmapSource bitmapSource = Clipboard.GetImage();

        JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        BitmapImage bImg = new BitmapImage();

        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmapSource));
        encoder.Save(memoryStream);

        bImg.BeginInit();
        bImg.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(memoryStream.ToArray());
        bImg.EndInit();

        memoryStream.Close();
        bitmap.Dispose();

        return bImg;


        //return (BitmapImage)i;
        //return i;
    }

    private static void SaveJpegXr(Bitmap bitmap, float quality, Stream output)
    {
        BitmapImage bitmapSource = Bitmap2BitmapImage((Bitmap)bitmap.Clone());
        //var bitmapSource = bitmap.ToWpfBitmap();
        var bitmapFrame = BitmapFrame.Create(bitmapSource);
        var jpegXrEncoder = new WmpBitmapEncoder();
        jpegXrEncoder.Frames.Add(bitmapFrame);
        jpegXrEncoder.ImageQualityLevel = quality / 100f;
        jpegXrEncoder.Save(output);
        bitmap.Dispose();


    }       
}
```

Is it just the case that doing these conversions is memory consuming by its very nature and as such calling it frequently from within a timer does not give the garbage collector time to dispose objects correctly?

Appreciate peoples wisdom on this...

Comment: You should Dispose() on Bitmap when you're done with them. Doing so will keep your memory usage low.

Comment: Hi, yes my fault forgot to include that line of code in this question.    It is disposing in my actual code so that is not the answer unfortunately but I really appreciated your time. Thanks

Comment: There is no need to convert Bitmap to BitmapImage for saving as JPEG, just call bitmap.Save() on it. You should edit your question to give an overview of what you're trying to achieve. Are you grabbing frames from a webcam and saving them, etc ... ?

Comment: Yes, I know all that.  But my question is specific here. There is a memory leak and I am focusing on that.

Comment: You can analyze with CLR Profiler or DebugdDiag.

Comment: To add info for you though.  I AM grabbing from a webcam.  I have noticed that by using a BitmapImage and compressing and then converting back to a jpeg that the quality is pretty good

Comment: @matt Hi, i will look into using those tools in a second. But, there are not many lines of code here so not much could be missed i would have thought?

Comment: @AndrewSimpson from the code, the dispose function are called. So I think it may not be the memory leak, just because it use too much memory. With these tools, you can better identify the problem

Comment: Hi, I appreciate your thoughts but i cannot see how I can code this any other way. If it is a memory leak inherent in calling these functions so frequently there will be nothing I could do I would have thought?